# What does an "Unable to validate data" exception in System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.GetDecodedData indicate

Tags: asp.net, exception

I've developed a website testing on localhost Cassini and it has always run fine, now when I deploy to my webserver I intermittently get the following error:

> Global.Application_Error Error: Exception occurred during request:
>   http://....blah.aspx Unable to validate data.    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.GetDecodedData(Byte[] buf,
>   Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Int32& dataLength)
>          at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) HttpApplication.RaiseOnError => EventHandler.Invoke =>
>   Global.Application_Error

This is being caught in my global.asax.  I've searched around but can't find the cause.  This exception is being thrown in extremely simple and small webforms.  The site is not hosted within a webfarm.

2 pages seem to cause this error intermittently and one of them stores a bool in the ViewState, but it is not modified apart from that.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://dotnetcoderoom.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/unable-to-validate-data-aspnet-error/

Cause:
The basic reason of this is the difference of key while encrypting and decrypting the viewstate data. Suppose an asp.net rendered a page with key1 and saved the page state in view state, meanwhile asp.net’s key is changed to key2, now when some server side event will occur on page the viewstate will get decrypted and this error will occur as the old view state is now not valid due to a different encryption key.

It may occur when you open a page for along time and after that do some events on that.

Solution
Fix the key in your web.config file, so that only one key is used to encrypt and decrypt the viewstate data.

For more information visit:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Programming_Languages/Dot_Net/ASP_DOT_NET/Q_21321364.html

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q312906

Comment: +1 Good answer - here's a public implementation of the code on the technet page: http://www.developmentnow.com/articles/machinekey_generator.aspx

Comment: I've added a machineKey into my web.config, and no errors yet, so hopefully this is the solution

Comment: I already have a machine key in my web.config and I still occasionally get this error. What do you suppose is causing it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't encountered that problem before. I'll see if I can find anything

Comment: I have a machine key element in web.config as well and am still getting these.

Comment: Then try to set: EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never". BEWARE: this shouldn't be done in public pages. Here is explanation (long thread): http://forums.asp.net/t/955145.aspx/2/10 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx

Answer (score 12):

I was getting `unable to validate data System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData` in my asp.net web app. I cleared my cookies, and the exception stopped.

Comment: You are definitely on to something. For me, what happened was that I changed an IIS website path to a different site that uses the same ASP.NET forms solution and the same domain-based cookies BUT a different machine key combination in web.config. So it thought the cookie was for the NEW site, but it wasn't. It choked when decrypting data encrypted by the previous site. Booya! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a machine key to your web.config to see if that fixes the error

http://aspnetresources.com/tools/keycreator.aspx

Comment: I've added a machineKey into my web.config, and no errors yet, so hopefully this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had two web applications (one was very old and another one I just created) and despite having the same machine key settings tickets generated in one application were not usable in another. That was fixed by adding `compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2"` as an argument for `machineKey` node in `web.config` in newer application.

Answer (score 0):

had the same error. The machinekey and decryptionKey was the same in all web.config but  some web.config had

```
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyFormsAuthenticationTicketCompatibility" value="true" />
```

and other did not. Removed this key from all web.config. I don't think the solution is in removing the key but in being the same in all web.config